# How to solve lifetime inside for_each

Tags: rust

I try to get the following code to compile.
Due to the `buffer` it wanted more explicit lifetimes inserted. So I tried that but still
cannot figure out yet how to make it also work in `for_each`.

```rust
use std::{sync::mpsc::Sender, ffi::OsStr};

use inotify::{Event, EventMask, Inotify, WatchMask};

pub struct Watcher<'a> {
    buffer: [u8; 1024],
    sender: Sender<Event<&'a OsStr>>,
}

impl <'a> Watcher<'a> {
    pub fn new(sender: Sender<Event<&OsStr>>) -> Watcher{
        Watcher{
            buffer: [0; 1024],
            sender: sender,
        }
    }
    pub fn watch_for_led_directories(&mut self, dir: String) {
        let sender = self.sender.clone();
        let mut inotify = Inotify::init().expect("Error while initializing inotify instance");

        // Watch for modify and close events.
        inotify
            .add_watch(dir, WatchMask::CREATE | WatchMask::DELETE)
            .expect("Failed to add file watch");

        // Read events that were added with `add_watch` above.
        
        let events = inotify
            .read_events_blocking(&mut self.buffer)
            .expect("Error while reading events");

        events.filter(|e| -> bool { !e.mask.intersects(EventMask::ISDIR) }).for_each(|e| sender.send(e).unwrap());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up giving up on no-copy of strings:

```rust
use std::{ffi::OsStr, sync::mpsc::Sender};

use inotify::{Event, EventMask, Inotify, WatchMask};

pub struct Watcher {
    buffer: [u8; 1024],
    sender: Sender<Event<String>>,
}

impl Watcher {
    pub fn new(sender: Sender<Event<String>>) -> Watcher {
        Watcher {
            buffer: [0; 1024],
            sender: sender,
        }
    }
    pub fn watch_for_led_directories(&mut self, dir: String) {
        let sender = self.sender.clone();
        let mut inotify = Inotify::init().expect("Error while initializing inotify instance");

        // Watch for modify and close events.
        inotify
            .add_watch(dir, WatchMask::CREATE | WatchMask::DELETE)
            .expect("Failed to add file watch");

        // Read events that were added with `add_watch` above.

        let events = inotify
            .read_events_blocking(&mut self.buffer)
            .expect("Error while reading events");

        let filter = |e: &Event<&OsStr>| -> bool {
            !e.mask.intersects(EventMask::ISDIR) || e.name.is_none()
        };
        events.filter(filter).for_each(|e| {
            sender
                .send(Event {
                    cookie: e.cookie,
                    mask: e.mask,
                    name: Some(e.name.unwrap().to_str().expect("Expected valid unicode string").into()),
                    wd: e.wd,
                })
                .unwrap()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while `self` has the lifetime of `'a`, `&mut self` in `watch_for_led_directories()` has a different lifetime.

`inotify.read_events_blocking()` returns `events` that [has the same lifetime](https://docs.rs/inotify/latest/inotify/struct.Inotify.html#method.read_events_blocking) as `&mut self.buffer`, which, as a mutable borrow, has the lifetime of `&mut self`. But `sender` is bound to life time `'a`. Therefore compiler cannot reconcile these two lifetimes.

One way to solve it is to provide an external buffer, instead of having it owned by `Watcher`, e.g.:

```
pub fn watch_for_led_directories(&self, buffer: &'a mut [u8], dir: String) {
...
        let events: Events = inotify
            .read_events_blocking(buffer)
            .expect("Error while reading events");
...
```

Compiler derives the lifetime of `events` from `buffer` and therefore it will be `'a`.

To use this method the externally allocated buffer must live at least as long as the `Watcher` object, which should not be too difficult to arrange.